# Make character blink when he get damage as feedback in unreal engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

How can i make my character blinks after receiving damage as a feedback for the player? 
Thanks!

Comment: What does your character's component panel look like?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom animation in blender then export it. Then make an animation blueprint for it then play it when you call the damage function you made. Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be it. Try this one:
https://youtu.be/NM1ET4uQOnc

If this isn't what you've been looking for or it doesn't work, then just tell me!